# Fetchmail won't run as daemon

Tags: fetchmail

I have fetchmail set up to grab emails from a Google account. If I set fetchmailrc ownership to `root:root` and run `fetchmail -vvv  --nodetach --nosyslog -f /etc/fetchmailrc`, it gets the emails as expected. If I set ownership to `fetchmail:root` and restart fetchmail then nothing happens. Permissions are 600. Here's my /etc/fetchmailrc:

```
set daemon 60
set invisible
set postmaster administrator
set no syslog
set logfile /var/log/fetchmail.log
poll pop.gmail.com protocol pop3 port 995 username "user@example.com" password "xxxxxx" ssl mda "/var/www/html/requesttracker/bin/rt-mailgate --queue YLN --action correspond --url https://subdomain.example.com" nokeep
```

How do I get the daemon to work?

**Update**: Further exploration has revealed that fetchmail isn't running. When I start fetchmail (`systemctl start fetchmail`), it doesn't return any errors so I've thought it was running. A status returns this:

```
● fetchmail.service - A remote-mail retrieval utility
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/fetchmail.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-10-27 06:49:23 MST; 2s ago
  Process: 51920 ExecStart=/usr/bin/fetchmail -d 300 --fetchmailrc /etc/fetchmailrc.example (code=exited, status=5)
 Main PID: 51920 (code=exited, status=5)

Oct 27 06:49:23 ylntest.yln.info systemd[1]: Started A remote-mail retrieval utility.
Oct 27 06:49:23 ylntest.yln.info systemd[1]: fetchmail.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=5/NOTINSTALL>
Oct 27 06:49:23 ylntest.yln.info systemd[1]: fetchmail.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Why does it fail? In particular, this line confuses me:
`ExecStart=/usr/bin/fetchmail -d 300 --fetchmailrc /etc/fetchmailrc.example`. Why is trying to load the example file?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. First, I went to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/fetchmail.service` and changed the ExecStart line to:
`ExecStart=/usr/bin/fetchmail -d 60 --fetchmailrc /etc/fetchmailrc`.

Then I changed ownership of `/etc/fetchmailrc` to `mail:mail` and I started fetchmail.